# Upgrading symfony project v2.8 to 3.4 - doctrine migrations error: The version "latest" couldn't be reached, there are no registered migrations

Tags: symfony-3.4, doctrine-migrations

Currently when trying to run migrations I am receiving this error:

```
[ERROR] The version "latest" couldn't be reached, there are no registered migrations.
```

My doctrine_migrations.yaml is:

```
doctrine_migrations:
     migrations_paths:
         'DoctrineMigrations': '%kernel.project_dir%/migrations'
     storage:
        table_storage:
             table_name: 'doctrine_migration_versions'
             version_column_name: 'version'
             version_column_length: 191
             executed_at_column_name: 'executed_at'
             execution_time_column_name: 'execution_time'
```

My doctrine-migrations-bundle version is: 3.0.x-dev
My old migrations files are in correct directory /migrations
Some registered migrations are in table doctrine_migration_versions.
I had to upgrade migration files (changed use class names & method up&down declaration - added :void as described in doctrine bundle upgrade.md).
I already ran command doctrine:migrations:sync-metadata-storage.
php app/console debug:config DoctrineMigrationsBundle - gives me this result:

```
doctrine_migrations:
    migrations_paths:
        DoctrineMigrations: /var/www/symfony/migrations
    storage:
        table_storage:
            table_name: doctrine_migration_versions
            version_column_name: version
            version_column_length: 191
            executed_at_column_name: executed_at
            execution_time_column_name: execution_time
    services: {  }
    factories: {  }
    migrations: {  }
    connection: null
    em: null
    all_or_nothing: false
    check_database_platform: true
    custom_template: null
    organize_migrations: false
```

php bin/console doctrine:migrations:status

```
+----------------------+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Configuration                                                                                                        |
+----------------------+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Storage              | Type                 | Doctrine\Migrations\Metadata\Storage\TableMetadataStorageConfiguration |
|                      | Table Name           | doctrine_migration_versions                                            |
|                      | Column Name          | version                                                                |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Database             | Driver               | Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDO\PgSQL\Driver                                  |
|                      | Name                 | postgres                                                               |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Versions             | Previous             | 20190131135201                                                         |
|                      | Current              | 20190220094110                                                         |
|                      | Next                 | Already at latest version                                              |
|                      | Latest               | 20190220094110                                                         |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Migrations           | Executed             | 126                                                                    |
|                      | Executed Unavailable | 126                                                                    |
|                      | Available            | 0                                                                      |
|                      | New                  | 0                                                                      |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Migration Namespaces | DoctrineMigrations   | /var/www/symfony/migrations                                            |
+----------------------+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

In migrations directory I have about newer 50 migrations not processed & not listed here.

What I should do now to move forward with this issue?